# Vertical Velocity of Projectile Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

**You throw a ball with velocity v0 = 22.0 m/s against a wall. You throw the ball upwards under an angle of
65.0° to the ground. The wall is s = 5.80 m away from your position.
a) What is the vertical and horizontal velocity of the ball leaving your hand?**

In the case of the vertical velocity, should I use the equation of "**Vy= Vo Sinθ - gt**" or should I use "**Vy= Vo Sinθ**"?

Answer (score 1):

In case of the vertical component of motion of the projectile, your initial velocity is $V_0\sin\theta$ and the equation of motion is $V_y=V_0\sin\theta-gt$. As the question asks for the vertical velocity of the ball leaving the hand, it must be equal to the initial vertical velocity i.e. $V_0\sin\theta$.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so, is it means if the question asked about the final vertical velocity, for instance, I will use this equation: Vy=V0sinθ−gt?

Comment: The equation $V_y=V_0\sin\theta-gt$ gives the vertical velocity at any moment in the projectile motion provided you know the time at which you want to find the vertical velocity. It's the general equation for vertical motion in projectile motion. If you plug in the time of flight in the equation, it will give you the final vertical velocity of the projectile.